# How to enable both HTTP and HTTPS in apache wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I want to enable both HTTP and HTTPS on my WordPress website. I enable SSL. Now HTTPS is working fine but when I try to open the website with HTTP then images, CSS, and JS are not loading due to the HTTPS.
Please help me or suggest to me how to enable both HTTP and HTTPS.

I tied the following code in the config file

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com' );
```

and in the functions.php file

```
update_option( 'siteurl', 'http://example.com' );
update_option( 'home', 'http://example.com' );
```

Still, images, CSS, and JS are not loading.

The website should open with both:

```
https://example.com
http://example.com
```

[image]

Comment: share your htaccess script

Comment: @Vel I have attached htaccess file

Comment: comment this HTTP_AUTHORIZATION code and check

Comment: mixed content error? you can have http site load https assets but you cant have it the other way around. make all your links https, then redirect from http to https

Comment: I commented and cleared the cache but getting same error

Comment: @LawrenceCherone all links are loading HTTPS. when I open the website `http://examle.com` then content and links are loading with HTTPS. 
Can it possible when open site with HTPP then links should load with HTTP.
And Open site with HTTPS then links should load with HTTPS.

Comment: Look at your browser devtools, specifically the console and network tabs. Do you see error messages? What do they say? Do View Source on your web page when it's served from http. Does it mention https in the URLs for your img, js, css assets?

Comment: Is it possible to enable both HTTP and HTTPS??

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Apart from that, this question doesn't look like programming-related. There are sites in the stackexchange network where it's on topic, I suggest moving it there.